# Populate dicts of number of ones to the left and right of bitstring

Tags: python

I have a bitstring like so: `1101100111` and I want to construct a dict of the number of ones to the left and the number of ones the right of any zero, eg:

`left = {2: 2, 5: 2, 6: 0}, right = {2: 2, 5: 0, 6: 3}`

In these dicts, the keys are the indexes and the values are the number of ones.
So at index 2 there are 2 ones to the left and 2 to the right. 
At index 5 there are 2 ones to the left and 0 to the right. 
At index 6 there are 0 ones to the left and 3 to the right.

I have this code:

```
    left, right, zeroes = {}, {}, []
    last_zero, last_one = 0, 0

    for i, v in enumerate(nums):
        if v == 0:
            left[i] = i - last_zero
            last_zero = i + 1
            zeroes.append(i)
        else:
            last_one = i

    print('left', left)
    print('right', right)
```

I can sort of 'hack' my way around to populate the 'left' dict, but populating the 'right' one is an issue.

Comment: Note, in principle, if you have an algorithm that works for the left, you could always just run it on `nums[::-1]` to get the right...

Comment: I prefer to run the loop once

Comment: @Christian-G I don't understand your dicts. Shouldn't the right dict be `{2: 5, 5: 3, 6: 3}`?

Comment: You could use `str.split()`, which might reduce some of the complexity in your loop.

Comment: Ahh I understand now, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can structure your logic.

```
var = str(1101100111)

idx = [i for i, j in enumerate(var) if j=='0']
counts = list(map(len, var.split('0')))

left = dict(zip(idx, counts))        # {2: 2, 5: 2, 6: 0}
right = dict(zip(idx, counts[1:]))   # {2: 2, 5: 0, 6: 3}
```

**Explanation**

- Convert your sequence to a string; and find indices of '0' elements.
- Split by '0' and extract length of each sequence of '1's.
- Finally, create left and right dictionaries using `dict(zip(x, y))`.

Comment: This is brilliant.  It's awesome `str.split()` does the right thing.

Answer (score -2):

Notice that `right[zeroes[i]] == left[zeroes[i+1]]` i.e. ones to the right of a zero are equal to ones to the left of next zero. You can easily generate the `left` dict and run a loop over `zeroes` to generate `right` dict.

```
for i in range(len(zeroes)-1):
    right[zeroes[i]] = left[zeroes[i+1]]
```

For the last zero, ones to the right can be given by trailing ones at the end of the string. This may probably give the answer, but be careful of some corner cases.

```
if last_one > last_zero:
    right[zeroes[-1]] = last_one - last_zero
else
    right[zeroes[-1]] = 0
```